# What are the differences between twilio video's group rooms and peer to peer rooms?

Tags: javascript, twilio, webrtc, twilio-api, twilio-video

I've had a look on twilio's documentation and I'm still unclear on what the differences are. Is the room API the same? Is there any case where I would use a group room in a 1:1 video call over peer-to-peer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.  From [this page](https://www.twilio.com/video):

"Add one-to-one or multi-party real-time voice and video to your app. Use Group Rooms to support up to 50 participants through a server-routed topology, or Peer-to-Peer Rooms to support up to 10 participants through a mesh topology."

Group Rooms route the video media through Twilios media servers.  Peer-to-Peer use WebRTCs peer-to-peer connections.

Loads of other info including some nifty diagrams on that page if you scroll down.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that I have, which is – assuming there are always under 10 participants, which one should be preferred?